# What is the purpose of using synchronized (Thread.currentThread())?

Tags: java, multithreading

Can any one please elaborate why the below code snippet gives IllegalMonitorStateException? I still can't able to find why and when this exception occurs and what is the purpose to lock on the current executing thread instead of object?

```
void waitForSignal() {
  Object obj = new Object();
  synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
   obj.wait();
   obj.notify();
  }
}
```

Comment: you MUST lock on the object. see documentation for [Object.wait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) and notify(): Throws:
    IllegalMonitorStateException - if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor.

Comment: Synchronizing on a Thread instance or the Thread class should be considered a REALLY BAD THING TO DO. This is because the Thread class does that itself (join/start/clone methods sync on the instance), and the constructor syncs on the class.
So if you sync on an instance, you basically lock out calls to join, start, clone and stop methods. If you sync on the class, you lock out thread creation.
I remember Josh Bloch saying at Devoxx 2011 that exposing AND internally using Object monitors is retrospectively one of the questionnable decision in the language design. Thread being his example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that exception because you need to acquire lock on `obj` before calling `wait()`, `notify()` or `notifyAll()` methods. These methods are designed to provide a mechanism to allow a thread to block until a specific condition is met.

The `wait()` method releases lock on the object, that mean you need to have acquired a lock before releasing it.

Whereas `notify()` and `notifyAll()` are to notify other threads which are waiting to acquire lock on the same object. It's like one thread is telling other threads : `"Dudes, I don't need the object for now, you can go ahead and use it. Make sure you notify me once you are done."`.

There are no real scenario where you would want to acquired lock on thread it self.

Here's a code block where you wait for thread to complete before executing a code block.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() { 
            synchronized (Thread.currentThread()) {
                System.out.println("Thread");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(10);//sleep main thread
    synchronized (t) {
        System.out.println("Main Thread");
    }
}
```

I have to sleep main thread becaue, Most of the time `synchronized` block acquires lock before the thread it self.

You can do the same with `join()`

Answer (score 2):

In order to call wait on `obj` that method/code block should synchronised on `obj`

```
void waitForSignal() {
  Object obj = new Object();
  synchronized (obj) {
   obj.wait();
   obj.notify();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
synchronized (Thread.currentThread())
```

doesnt make any sense, a thread cant synchronize itself (that'd produce a deadlock), you will have to synchronize on the OBJECT YOU ARE WAITING FOR:

```
synchronized (obj)
```

Also : its always better to use [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for this kind of job

Comment: Synchronizing on any Thread object is a Bad Idea (See @AmitChotaliya's answer for why), but simply synchronizing on Thread.currentThread() will _not_ guarantee a self-deadlock.  Try it and see.

Comment: "It's always better to use semaphore for this kind of job."  For _what_ kind of job?  The OP's example is too small to tell us what problem he is trying to solve.  Semaphores _are_ a more natural fit to some kinds of problem than wait() and notify(), but not to _every_ kind of problem.

Comment: i see people really like to take given words, turn them around and try to put up a strawman-argument nowadays ....

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking locking on the thread makes no sense *except* for blocking operations on the Thread object itself.  For example `Thread.join()` wait()s on the Thread to finish.  This means it uses a synchronised block with `wait()` to wait on the thread itself.